# Improper configuration or mysqlclient not installed, but I have mysqlclient version site-packages (1.4.6)

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, mysql-python, ubuntu-20.04

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Everything was working properly in Ubuntu 18.04, but after I upgraded my OS from 18.04 to 20.04 it is now showing this error in django:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

After that I tried this command:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Results of `pip install mysqlclient`:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.4.6)
```

I also tried:

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

It gave a version error.

Comment: It's a good idea to use a virtual environment instead of installing into the system's site packages. You'll avoid the *is not writeable* error. The [django-girls](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_installation/#virtual-environment) tutorial explains how to get started with a virtual environment.

Comment: `pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()` is for [`PyMySQL`](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/), it won't help if you are trying to install `mysqlclient`.

Comment: i follow many stackoverflow question and do may stuff but in last i retry pip install --force-reinstall --ignore-installed --no-binary :all: mysqlclient
and then boom it is working . but i doubt what is the proper reason

Comment: i know using virtual environment is good but i am using in my lappy for personal practices so i don't want every time activate particular environment ,i am little lazy but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
pip install --force-reinstall --ignore-installed --no-binary :all: mysqlclient
```